Grounding of battery-powered devices
I have a device that I am prototyping that can be powered from either 5V USB power (via a Mini-B connector) or batteries (combined 6V). Power from either of the two is switched with a SP3T switch, with the middle pin being unconnected (i.e. OFF).
However, in the circumstance that the device is being powered from USB, and there are batteries (assume generic alkaline) still in the device connected to GNDD in the schematic(positive terminal of the batteries are left floating), would this arrangement be 'safe', i.e. no battery damage?
Essentially, the entire circuit shares the same ground, with a different power supply being selected by the SP3T switch, whether they are batteries or USB bus power.


Is this what you meant?

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
This is fine.
